# "Jmeter - Cannot record Facebook/Messenger - 501 method not implemented"

Tags: facebook, jmeter, record, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to record some talk on Facebook Messenger to measure the response time, but i when i'm using HTTP Recorder with Proxy on Facebook, this error appears:

> 501 Method not implemented
>
> Service not implemented. Probably used https instead of http. To
>   record https requests, see HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder documentation

I already installed the JMeter certificate and i don't know what i can do to record something on Facebook.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to record scripts on mobile Facebook messenger in Jmeter, you can try blazemeter recorder.

[Blazemeter script recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web)

Hope this helps you..